# GitHub Pages: Configuring Base URL for Jekyll Blog

Tags: html, url, github, jekyll, github-pages

I have Setup a Jekyll Blog for GitHub pages for User.
https://github.com/bitgeeky/bitgeeky.github.io

It works fine locally. But on GitHub pages the css files are not getting served.
The error in browser console is:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://pankajmalhotra.com/public/css/main.css
```

I suspect some problem with the URL path since the page is loading otherwise.

What changes should I make to get the css files and images served ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's because Github Pages uses jekyll 1.5.1. See [Dependency versions](https://pages.github.com/versions/).

Your repository uses SASS, which was only introduced in jekyll 2.0.0. See [Jekyll History](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/history/#major-enhancements).

So you might want to compile your `main.scss` manually and point all references to generated `main.css`, then push `main.css` to Github.

Comment: Thanks for your response Yi Zeng, I am using a Jekyll theme for my website and its already working here http://aigarsdz.github.io/brume/  and the source is https://github.com/aigarsdz/brume. So there must be something else that I am missing.

Comment: You are correct I changes the SASS to CSS it worked, and for the original theme the master branch was different from the gh-pages branch so it created some confusion.